# Why is this texture not showing up?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, stb-image, glad

I am following the tutorial from learnopengl.com to make a game engine.

I am using stb_image.h to load the textures, and my own header file to compile and link the shaders.

I got to the part in Getting Started/Textures where the container.jpg texture is supposed to fill up the rectangle on the window. But whenever I compile and run the code the texture does not appear anywhere in the window. This is my texture loading code:

```
    // Load and create a texture
    unsigned int texture1;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    // Set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // Set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // Load image, create texture, and generate minmaps
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\C++ Projects\\Working Game Engine\\container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data) {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture(s)\n";
    }
```

These are the quad's coords:

```
    float vertices[] = {
        // Positions         // Colors          // Texture Coords
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3
    };
```

Render code:

```
        // Process inputs
        processInput(window);
        // Render
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Bind Texture
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
        // Render Container
        ourShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        // Swap buffers and poll IO events (Key pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
```

Vertex shader code:

```
#version 460 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

Fragment shader code:

```
#version 460 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

Note that no error codes are returned from the image loader or shader compilers.
[The rectangle appears like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxK3U.png)

Comment: What's your texturecoordinates? Do you somewhere set the `texture1` uniform?

Comment: @BDL I updated the question the with coordinates, and the tutorial never said anything about setting the texture1 uniform. Where and how could I do this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the texture1 uniform like this:

```
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "texture1"), 0);
```

Comment: That's in general a good idea, although the default value of a sampler uniform is 0, so it probably doesn't change much here.

Comment: @BDL where do I do this, in the frag shader?

Comment: @BDL true, maybe he forgot to set the vertex attribute for the texture coordinates

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out I didn't glEnableVertexAttribArray(); the texture coords. Quite embarrassing.